# Open an HttpURLConnection in a browser

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, oauth

I am working on a jsp page which uses a bean to create an OAuth authenticated HttpURLConnection and am able to connect successfully.  Is there anyway that I can take that open HttpURLConnection and somehow display the contents in a browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to display the contents of a stream from another web page in a jsp is if you do not get the output stream yourself. If I remember right, the output stream for a jsp is automatically retrieved when an output character outside the scriptlet tags is envountered by the parser.

This would be better done in a servlet proper rather than a jsp. Just get the url connection, get the output stream and pipe it to the servlet's output stream using a loop.